# How do I install/use PhpRedis on Google App Engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, redis, phpredis

I would like to use the super fast PhpRedis on Google App Engine, how does one go about doing that if its possible?

Comment: This question is far to broad. Please read [What topics can I ask about on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhpRedis is a PHP extension, and it is not on currently supported on App Engine.

For reference
https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_Enabled_extensions

There is a PHP implementation which uses sockets and covers basic redis commands. But without knowing your use case it's difficult to recommend.

Tom

Comment: Yeah, it sucks, was hoping for a "Googler" to tell me that they're adding it soon, thanks Tom. The framework I'm using only supports PhpRedis flavour at the moment, so I guess memcache will have to do for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable PhpRedis on App Engine with PHP 7.2 (beta) in the Standard Environment through [Dynamically Loadable Extensions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/runtime#dynamically_loadable_extensions).

Add `extension=redis.so` to app.yaml to enable it.